# How to check if a checkbox is checked, and change data in another cell based on it, repeated for multiple rows

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to make a script that, whenever triggered, runs through each row checking if the checkboxes in column F are checked. If so, the content of column A in that row is replaced with a 0. Upon running the code, nothing happens. I am not sure where the script gets caught up, but I would assume it's in the for() loop. I have also included a picture of the spreadsheet itself for easier understanding. Any help is appreciated.

My code:

```
function onEditButAgain(event){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var editedCell = sheet.getActiveCell();
  var columnToSortBy = 6;

  if(editedCell.getColumn() == columnToSortBy)
  {   
    for(var x = 2; x<=100; x++)
    { 
      var checked = sheet.getRange(x, 6);
      if(checked.isChecked == true)
      {
        var date = sheet.getRange(x, 1);
        date.setValue("0");
      }
    } 
  }
}
```

The image of the spreadsheet itself:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

### Explanation:

Your goal is to manually execute a script that will change the value in column A whenever the cell in the same row in column F is checked.

- The obvious issue in the code is `isChecked` which should be `isChecked()`. You use parenthesis when you want to execute a function and in this case you want to execute `isChecked`.
- In this case, an `onEdit` script will be redundant. If you want to use an `onEdit` trigger with the name `onEditButAgain` you have to create an [installable](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) trigger. But you don't need an installable trigger for this purpose.
- Although you can wrap up the following code in this answer in a simple `onEdit()` function, the event object is not used and the code won't be 100% efficient. But if you want to run it manually, you don't need a trigger anyway.
- When you use a loop, it is not a good practice to use methods like `getRange` or `isChecked` or `setValue` because these methods are computationally expensive and your script will very slow. Work with arrays instead and `getValues`/`setValues`.

### Solution:

```
function myFunction(){
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1'); // change it to your sheet name
  const valA = sh.getRange('A2:A'+sh.getLastRow()).getValues().flat();
  const cb = sh.getRange('F2:F'+sh.getLastRow()).getValues().flat();
  const new_valA = cb.map((c,i)=> [c ? "0" : valA[i]]);
  sh.getRange(2,1,new_valA.length,new_valA[0].length).setValues(new_valA);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! However, when I run this, I get an error message of "TypeError: Cannot read property 'getRange' of null." I think this is because there are some empty rows towards the bottom of this range. How would I go about solving this? (I don't want to have to update the range each time I add a new row since I'll be doing that quite often.)

Comment: @ZhediKnight the reason for the error is that you haven't changed the `Sheet1` part in the code to the name of your sheet as I commented in the code. Replace `Sheet1` with the name of **your** sheet. Regarding the other topic you mentioned. I updated the code to consider until the last row of the sheet. If this does not work properly (because you have other values below the A and F column range, then you have to share a copy of your sheet with me. It will be much quicker to find a solution when you can see the actual sheet.

Comment: @ZhediKnight I updated the code in your file. go to the script editor and execute `myFunction`.

Comment: Thanks, I did, but since I'm new to Stack Overflow it doesn't visually update it :/ sorry!